# How to change System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.Add method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like custom behaviour for `myListBox.Items.Add` and `myListBox.Items.Remove`. I subclassed ListBox and intended to assign a custom extension of ItemCollection to its Items property, but ItemCollection is sealed and I can't extend it.

How can I make `myListBox.Items.Add` do something additional every single time?

Comment: Can you specify what is the additional work you want to do when adding an item?

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the `ItemsControl.OnItemsChanged` method:

```cs
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
  protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnItemsChanged(e);

    switch (e.Action)
    {
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
        break;
      case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```